# Execute stored procedure in EF Core 3.0 vs 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to update my code to accommodate changes in EF Core 3.0, specifically the deprecation of `ExecuteSqlCommand`.

The following code was working in 2.2 but as stated, I need to get rid of `ExecuteSqlCommand`:

```
SqlParameter srcid = new SqlParameter("@srcCharacterId", participantApplication.CharacterId);
SqlParameter newid = new SqlParameter("@newCharacterId", newCharacterId);
SqlParameter pResult = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@pResult",
    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit,
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
};

_db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("pCharacterCopy @srcCharacterId, @newCharacterId, @pResult OUTPUT", srcid, newid, pResult);
```

I've tried changing the call to `ExecuteSqlRaw` (leaving everything else identical) but that, although it compiles, throws the following exception at run time:

> The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects

I've checked with the debugger and none of the `SqlParameter` are null. I suspect my call to `ExecuteSqlRaw` is not formatted correctly but I cannot find any examples other than integrating calls into Linq queries which I don't need to do.  I just want to fire off the call to the stored procedure and take a look at the output parameter when it is done.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is most likely due to the [switch to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#SqlClient).

Remove the reference to the System.Data.SqlClient assembly and replace the namespaces.

`using System.Data.SqlClient;` => `using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;`