# ExecuteSqlRaw parametric query in .NET Core 3

Tags: c#, parameters, .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to execute a parametric query in C#, the code is this:

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[ShoppingListShop] " +
                                    "([PlaceId], " +
                                    "[Name], " +
                                    "[Address], " +
                                    "[Location], " +
                                    "[NorthEast], " +
                                    "[SouthWest], " +
                                    "[Date], " +
                                    "[LocationLat], " +
                                    "[LocationLng], " +
                                    "[NorthEastLat], " +
                                    "[NorthEastLng], " +
                                    "[SouthWestLat], " +
                                    "[SouthWestLng])" +
              "VALUES(" +
                                    "@placeId, " +
                                    "@name, " +
                                    "@address, " +
                                    "GEOGRAPHY::Point(@lat, @lng, 4326), " +
                                    "GEOGRAPHY::Point(@nelat, @nelng, 4326), " +
                                    "GEOGRAPHY::Point(@swlat, @swlng, 4326), " +
                                    "SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), " +
                                    "@lat, " +
                                    "@lng, " +
                                    "@nelat, " +
                                    "@nelng, " +
                                    "@swlat, " +
                                    "@swlng);";

SqlParameter placeIdPrm = new SqlParameter("@placeId", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
SqlParameter namePrm = new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
SqlParameter addressPrm = new SqlParameter("@address", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
SqlParameter latPrm = new SqlParameter("@lat", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18);
SqlParameter lngPrm = new SqlParameter("@lng", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18);
SqlParameter neLatPrm = new SqlParameter("@nelat", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18);
SqlParameter neLngPrm = new SqlParameter("@nelng", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18);
SqlParameter swLatPrm = new SqlParameter("@swlat", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18);
SqlParameter swLngPrm = new SqlParameter("@swlng", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18);

placeIdPrm.Value = shop.PlaceId;
namePrm.Value = shop.Name;
addressPrm.Value = shop.Address;

latPrm.Value = shop.LocationLat;
lngPrm.Value = shop.LocationLng;

neLatPrm.Value = shop.NorthEastLat;
neLngPrm.Value = shop.NorthEastLng;

swLatPrm.Value = shop.SouthWestLat;
swLngPrm.Value = shop.SouthWestLng;

SqlParameter[] parametri = new SqlParameter[9] { placeIdPrm, namePrm, addressPrm, latPrm, lngPrm, neLatPrm, neLngPrm, swLatPrm, swLngPrm };

sqlServerDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql, parametri);
```

For some reason I get this exception

> The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: tip: use `@"verbatim string literals"` for your SQL - it can have line-breaks in without making it impossible to read

Comment: unrelated, but this would be *much* cleaner and simpler with "Dapper"; I'm biased, but: you might want to check it out, at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark based on the error message, but: is it possible that you are using both `System.Data.SqlClient` and `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`? i.e. `sqlServerDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw`  is expecting a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[]` (and instances), and you've given it a `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[]` (and instances)? (or vice versa) - try "go to definition" on `SqlParameter`, and see where it is coming from.

Comment: no, I'm using System.Data.SqlClient; the the SqlParameter are System.Data.SqlClient, but in the "go to definition" of ExecuteSqlRaw I jump into Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: @Francesco and is it possible that EntityFrameworkCore is now using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`? perhaps via the connection string? try looking at `sqlServerDbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().FullName`

Comment: thaks for the suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59655923/execute-stored-procedure-in-ef-core-3-0-vs-2-2 you are right, let me try with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient instead of System.Data.SqlClient for the SqlParameter

Comment: yes, it works, as you suggested before and I see in another post, in effect, the solution consist in removing the reference to the System.Data.SqlClient assembly and replace the namespaces.

using System.Data.SqlClient; => using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

Comment: @Francesco sometimes, you can hit a bullseye with a shot in the dark